# How can I see the skill points of each of the characters in Mass Effect 2?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I want to see the skill points of each of the characters to decide whether I want to retrain any. How can I see the skill points of each of the characters in Mass Effect 2?

Comment: You mean the total skill points they'd have available if you respecced them? I think it's just based on level. Why not just respec & then not save to check?

Comment: Because respect them costs element zero.

Comment: @RavenDreamer because respecing them costs element zero and I don't have enough to do it for everybody.

Comment: Yeah, so reload your old save once you see how much they have, that way you get the information and you haven't spent any Eezo.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post in gameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/944907-mass-effect-2/53810963) the only possible way to level up the skill points of the squad members is by selecting them and going on a mission. Thus I believe the only way to see their skill points is by doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways:

1. By visiting the Med Lab in the Normandy
2. By assigning them when selecting them to your squad.

I mostly play ME3 nowadays, but I believe it's the same for ME2.